# "Как бы часто н* делали это, все равно н* будут". "Не" или "ни"?

Tags: не-или-ни

Очень нужна подсказка. "Не" или "ни"?

...а другие, как бы часто н* делали это, все равно н* будут...

Comment: Фразу целиком не приведете? Пока есть определенные сомнения.
Хотя, похоже, что Виктор1799 прав.
.. а другие, как бы часто ***ни*** делали это, все равно ***не*** будут...

Answer (score 2):

Здесь должна быть только усилительная частица НИ, так как она находится в придаточном уступительном. Да и по логике можно понять, что речь идет не о том, что НЕ делали, а о том, что делали, и делали часто

Answer (score 1):

> ...а другие, как бы часто н* делали это, все равно н* будут...

Если действие происходит, причём неоднократно, то частица НИ усиливает утверждение, содержащееся в первой части данной фразы. Вторая часть содержит отрицание, выраженное частицей НЕ. Поэтому верный вариант следующий:

**...а другие, как бы часто ни делали это, все равно не будут...**